# Expex and RL language (Arabic) with LR free text (English)

Tags: arabic, expex

I am trying to use expex for interlinear glossing with the main text in a RL language (Arabic) but the free text in a LR language (English). As you can see from the output, the RL language formatting is taking over the formatting of the free text. How do I get expex to use LR for the free text only?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% extra packages
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% dimensions
\newlength{\defparindent}
\setlength{\defparindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% custom ling styles
\definelingstyle{Text}{aboveexskip=0pt,belowexskip=0pt,
  belowglpreambleskip=0pt,aboveglftskip=0pt,glwordalign=left,
  glftpos=right,glhangstyle=none,ssratio=.60,
  everygla=\arabicfont}

% font
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\begin{document}

\exdisplay[lingstyle=Text]
\begin{Arabic}
\begingl
\gla
اِسْمي هَيْشم نَجّار. طالِنٌ في كُلًِيَّةِ العُلومِ في جامِعَةِ دِمَشْق. في
//
\glb
Name Haisham Najjar Student in college science at University Damascus In
//
\glft
My name is Haisham Najjar. I am a student in the college of science
at Damascus University.
//
\endgl
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Seems that \textenglish{My name is Haisham Najjar. I am a student in the college of science at Damascus University.} does what I want. Is there a way I can add this automatically to the Text lingstyle?

Comment: I don't think so, since you are in an Arabic glossing environment with your `\begin{arabic}` and `\end{arabic}`. You could use `paracol` instead of `\glft` and define all the `paracol` stuff separately. As a side note, for now, add  `everyglft=\raggedleft` to your `lingstyle` so that your `\glft` is properly aligned. I'll add a MWE below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `\textenglish{...}` will fix the RL problem.

`\glft \textenglish{My name is Haisham Najjar. I am a student in the college of science at Damascus University.}`

EDIT: also added in `everyglft=\raggedleft` to the `lingstyle`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% extra packages
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% dimensions
\newlength{\defparindent}
\setlength{\defparindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% custom ling styles
\definelingstyle{Text}{
    aboveexskip=0pt,
    belowexskip=0pt,
    belowglpreambleskip=0pt,
    aboveglftskip=0pt,
    glwordalign=left,
    glftpos=right,
    glhangstyle=none,
    ssratio=.60,
    everygla=\arabicfont,
    everyglft=\raggedleft
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
% font
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Andalus}

\begin{document}

\exdisplay[lingstyle=Text]
\begin{Arabic}
\begingl
\gla
اِسْمي هَيْشم نَجّار. طالِنٌ في كُلًِيَّةِ العُلومِ في جامِعَةِ دِمَشْق. في //

\glb
Name Haisham Najjar Student in college science at University Damascus In //

\glft
\textenglish{My name is Haisham Najjar. I am a student in the college of science at Damascus University.} //
\endgl
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```